# Dagger2 and Architectural Components - Kotlin compiler error

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I tried to build following project but I receive some errors: https://github.com/bufferapp/android-clean-architecture-mvi-boilerplate

1 - Kotlin compiler error :

```
error: no interface expected here
public class ViewModelFactory extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory {
```

ViewModelFactory is as follow:

```
@Singleton
open class ViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>

    @Inject constructor(creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>,
            @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) {
        this.creators = creators
    }

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        var creator: Provider<out ViewModel>? = creators[modelClass]
        if (creator == null) {
            for ((key, value) in creators) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(key)) {
                    creator = value
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass)
        }
        try {
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }
}
```

2 - Kotlin compiler error :

```
error: @Binds methods must have only one parameter whose type is assignable to the return type
    public abstract android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

It happens on following class :

```
@Module
abstract class PresentationModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(BrowseBufferoosViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindBrowseBufferoosViewModel(viewModel: BrowseBufferoosViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

Could anyone suggest me how to resolve errors?

Comment: Known bug reported @ jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-27506